# Python: subprocess.Popen variable behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to read all files in a directory and pass them via command line to another program.
The following is a part of my code (for one file here) which does not seem to work, and I don't really understand why it would not work.
My code (with a bit of debug print):

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# Python 3

avidemux_dir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Avi Demux\\avidemux.exe"
start_dir = "F:\\aaa"          # without ending backslash!
extension = ".mpg"

import os
import subprocess


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_dir):
    if filenames:
        first_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filenames[0])
        test2 = "--load " + first_file        

print(dirpath)                #results in: F:\aaa\av01
print(first_file)             #results in: F:\aaa\av01\av01.mpg
print(test2)                  #results in: --load F:\aaa\av01\av01.mpg


p1 = subprocess.Popen([avidemux_dir, "--load", first_file])
p2 = subprocess.Popen([avidemux_dir, test2])
```

For this example, avidemux will work (load the correct file) only for p1. p2 does not work.
Why is that?

The commandline example that works in .bat:

```
avidemux.exe --load F:\aaa\av01\av01.mpg
```

I really would like to have it all in one string like in p2 because I join a larger list of files together to one big string with the correct variables for avidemux.

Comment: Are you expecting the file to be loaded and stored in `p1`?

Comment: unrelated: you could use raw string literals such as `r"F:\aaa"` (notice: `r""` prefix) to avoid escaping backslashes in Windows paths.

Answer (score 2):

`shlex` is one approach, but from the files paths it's obvious you're running on Windows, and `shlex` assumes conventions used in Unix-ish shells.  They can get you in trouble on Windows.

As the docs say, the underlying Windows API call takes a single string as an argument, so on Windows you're generally much better off passing a single string to `Popen()`.

Oops!  I see you've already discovered that.  But at least now you know *why* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
import shlex
p2 = subprocess.Popen([avidemux_dir] + shlex.split(test2))
```

see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) about command args of Popen.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you're passing a string of two arguments there. You need to split it, if necessary using `shlex.split`:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen([avidemux_dir, *shlex.split(test2)])
```

Or just pass a string:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(avidemux_dir + ' ' + test2, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across the solution: Not using a list, when doing something like that.
Solution:

```
test2 = avidemux_dir + " --load " + first_file
```

and

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(test2)  # no more list but the pure string.
```

Comment: Should it be `p2 = subprocess.Popen(test2, shell=True)`?

Comment: @atupal, the OP isn't using any shell metacharacters here, so `shell=True` doesn't appear to make good sense.

Comment: @TimPeters But for example , if we use `subprocess.Popen("ls -l")`, it will make the "-l" as the file, and raise the "No such file or directory" error, when use `subprocess.Popen("ls -l", shell=True)` or `subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l"])`, it works. From the docs, is says:The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Comment: @atupal, the OP is running on Windows.  *No* way of spelling "ls -l" will work for them ;-)  If, e.g., they want to run "dir /ad" on Windows, then they do need to say `shell=True`, but that's because `dir` is implemented **by** the Windows command shell.  On Windows, the underlying API call to create the process **always** requires a single string; pass some list, and on Windows Python tries to guess the best way to turn it into a string in such a way that the Windows API will break it back up into separate arguments.  Windows is very different from Linux here under the covers.

Comment: @TimPeters: `ls` might work in PowerShell or if coreutils for Windows is installed.